# python using huggingface LLM is having issues on the response

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

Every time so far the first response is always the provided persona, and after that once repeated it gives a random and scrappy response, but will continue on until it hits the set limit. After it hits the set limitation, it acts as if it were supposed to end there. example:

You: hi rikka (my input)
Rikka's Persona: a childish, immature girl
You: hi rikka (my input)
Rikka: You: hi rikka
Rikka: hi
Toni: I'm not here to get into a fight with you
Rikka: lol
Toni: I'm here because you have been so mean to me
Rikka: what
Toni: you have been so mean to me
Rikka: you are a bad person
Toni: I'm not mad
Toni: you are a bad person
Toni: you are a bad
You: (prompting input)

I am supposed to get a casual response as if I were chatting to a friend. I have tried settinf response limits, using 5 different models (and fixing the code accordingly with the same result).

here is the current code I have.
I am new here, so pardon me if I do things wrong.

Python

````
# Load tokenizer and model
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-neo-1.3B")
model = GPTNeoForCausalLM.from_pretrained("EleutherAI/gpt-neo-1.3B")

# Set up persona and character name
character_name = "Rikka"
persona_description = "a childish, immature girl

# Flag to indicate if persona has been introduced
persona_introduced = False

while True:
    # Get user input
    user_input = input("You: ")

    if not persona_introduced:
        # Introduce persona for the first user input
        print(f"{character_name}'s Persona: {persona_description}")
        persona_introduced = True
    else:
        # Use user input in dialogue history
        input_prompt = f"You: {user_input}\n{character_name}:"

        # Tokenize the input
        input_ids = tokenizer.encode(input_prompt, return_tensors="pt")

        # Generate the response
        output = model.generate(
            input_ids,
            max_length=100,
            pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
            num_return_sequences=1,
            do_sample=True,
            top_k=50,
            top_p=0.95,
            temperature=0.7,
        )

        # Decode and print the response
        response = tokenizer.decode(output[0], skip_special_tokens=True).strip()
        print(f"{character_name}: {response}")```
````

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same challenge. You have to tweak the right parameters to get the appropriate response. This is how I setup mine:

```
    # Tokenize the prompt and generate response
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(prompt, return_tensors="pt")
output = model.generate(
    input_ids,
    pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    max_new_tokens=40,
    num_beams=5,
    no_repeat_ngram_size=2,
    num_return_sequences=5,
    early_stopping=True,
    do_sample=True,
    top_k=0
)
generated_text = tokenizer.decode(output[:, input_ids.shape[-1]:][0], skip_special_tokens=True)
```

You can find the parameters for gpt2 here: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/text_generation

More reading to help you get started: https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-generate